# Disabling Field in Apex using JavaScript

Tags: html, apex

it appears that there is no Apex tag to disable it , so I tried to use Javascript to disable a field with value VAR in it, but its not working

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("[id$=type]").change(function(){
                if(this.value=="VAR"){
                        $("[id$=type]").val("");

                        $("input[id$=type]").prop("disabled",true);                       

                }

            });
        });
    </script>


<apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2">
        <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Type}" id="type" />

      </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log('Im ready');
            $(".disableClass").attr("disabled", true)
        });
    </script>
```

and you would need styleClass

```
<apex:inputField value="{!acc.Type}" id="type" styleClass="disableClass" />
```